# Writing POM Version with use of properties file

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I would like to write the POM Version and a timestamp in a text file.

Therefore I created a properties file in a `src/main/resources/version` folder with:

```
product.version = ${project.version}
```

and added to my `pom.xml`:

```
<resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/version</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

My output textfile says this:

```
Version = ${project.version}
Timestamp = 277466182879304
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The variable is called `${project.version}`, not `${pom.version}`

**[EDIT]** Old versions of the m2e plugin could be configured not to run the resource copy target of Eclipse when Eclipse builds the project. That means for unit tests and `main()` methods that you launch from Eclipse, the resources won't be updated and you will see some old value.

Also make sure you force a complete rebuild of the projects when running Maven from the command line; otherwise, Eclipse will be confused and you will get strange errors.

If you have problems like this, first run Maven from the command line to see whether it's a Maven or m2e (configuration) issue.

The next step is to run Maven from within Eclipse using `Run as.../Maven install`. That will build the project using Maven and without the m2e shortcuts.

If those work, it's an effect of m2e which tries to cut some corners to keep Eclipse responsive. Make sure you have the latest version of m2e (1.2.0). It should fix this. If it still doesn't work, file a bug report.

This works for me: `version.properties` contains

```
version=${project.version}
timestamp=${build.time}
```

Because of a bug in Maven 3.x, I have to use a plugin to get a correct build timestamp:

```
                   <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.keyboardsamurais.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-timestamp-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                    <propertyName>build.time</propertyName>
                                    <timestampPattern>yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss</timestampPattern>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>create</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

Comment: Typing error. I have $(project.version) but still don't get the actual version number

Comment: @dutchman79 It should be `${project.version}` and not `$(project.version)` - curly brackets, not parenthesis.

Comment: You need to use curly brackets instead of braces.

Comment: Yep, just saw my second typing error in one question. But my error still is the same. In the output file there is no version number written but Version = ${project.version}. This value does somehow still not get written.

Comment: Do you use the m2e plugin of Eclipse or do you start Maven from the command line?

Comment: I use the m2e plugin. I don't understand why the version placeholder is never written